# When is the question timestamp shown in the flag dashboard for a flagged answer?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

In the flag dashboard, when viewing answer flags, the timestamp of the question is sometimes shown, sometimes not:

[image]

Under what conditions is it shown, and what is the reasoning behind this? It's not the type of flag; I noticed this behaviour for two nearly identical custom moderator flags as well.